# Dist of a Frequency in Haskell using a call to foldmap

Tags: haskell, distribution, frequency

I am very new to Haskell. What could I replace the "undefined" in the definition below so that the "frequencies"
calculates the frequency distribution of items in the input list. For example,
the expression "frequencies [True, False, True]" should produce a distribution
where True has a frequency of 2 and False has a frequency of 1.

I can add new top-level function definitions, but not modify any other
part of the definition of "frequencies". In particular, I can't add any
additional named arguments or remove the call to "foldMap" in the definition of
"frequencies".

```
type Dist a = a -> Sum

frequencies :: Eq a => [a] -> Dist a
 frequencies = foldmap = undefined
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `frequencies = foldMap undefined`? Also, please include the definition of `Dist`. Is it something like `type Dist a = [(a, Int)]`?

Comment: @JonPurdy I added the definition of dist and yes, foldmap was missing as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement this by following the types using GHC *typed holes*, entering an underscore `_` to ask the compiler what type of an expression should be.

```
import Data.Semigroup (Sum(..))

-- Using the standard 'Sum' for illustration.
type Dist a = a -> Sum Int

frequencies :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Dist a
frequencies = foldMap _
```

Here, the compiler reports that `_ :: a -> Dist a`. So we’re given each `a` value in the input, and must produce a corresponding `Dist a`, which are then combined into a final result with `foldMap`. This relies on the fact that there are `Semigroup` and `Monoid` instances for functions, which just combine their results:

```
instance (Semigroup m) => Semigroup (a -> m) where
  f <> g = \ x -> f x <> g x

instance (Monoid m) => Monoid (a -> m) where
  mempty = \ _x -> mempty
```

`Dist a` is a function that accepts an `a` and returns a `Sum`, which may be combined using its `Semigroup`/`Monoid` instances to add the results. So we want to introduce a lambda:

```
frequencies :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Dist a
frequencies = foldMap (\ x -> _)
```

The hole now has type `Dist a`, which is a function, so we introduce another parameter:

```
frequencies :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Dist a
frequencies = foldMap (\ x -> \ y -> _)
```

Now we must produce a `Sum Int` value. All we have are two `a` values, and a constraint that `a` can be compared with `Eq`. So let’s introduce an `if` to test their equality:

```
frequencies :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Dist a
frequencies = foldMap (\ x -> \ y -> if x == y then _ else _)
```

What `Sum` values should we use for the holes? Presumably we want to add 1 to the total if the values are equal, and nothing if they differ. So we can use `Sum 1` for the true case, and `mempty` (or `Sum 0`) for the false case. We can also collapse the lambda using the normal syntactic sugar for multiple parameters.

```
frequencies :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Dist a
frequencies = foldMap (\ x y -> if x == y then Sum 1 else mempty)
```

Now we can call this function on a list, and it will produce a function that gives us the frequency for a particular element.

```
> f = frequencies "AAB"
> :t f
f :: Dist Char
> f 'A'
Sum {getSum = 2}
> f 'B'
Sum {getSum = 1}
```

From this, we can build more interesting things, like a histogram:

```
import Data.List (nub)

histogram :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
histogram xs = let
  keys = nub (sort xs)
  frequency = frequencies xs
  in zip keys (map (getSum . frequency) keys)
```

```
> histogram "AAB"
[('A',2),('B',1)]
```

Comment: This is one of the most thoughtful answers I've ever received on this website, thank you.